# xyplot how to swap the default colour

Tags: r, colors, lattice

I have a dataframe called **df**

```
 clust    gender    conf    chall
   1        F        2        6
   2        M        4        1
   1        M        5        2
   1        F        3        5
   3        F        3        4
```

I want to make an xyplot from the **lattic** package as below:

```
xyplot(chall ~ conf, 
   data = df,
   group = gender, 
   auto.key = list(space = 'right'),
   jitter.x = T, jitter.y = T)
```

The problem is that the default colour assigns 'Blue' to females and 'Pink' to males. I just want to swap these colours. I understand it might be a basic question but I am unable to find a solution to this.

The SO posts that I looked at, were for more advanced changes in plot settings and were not useful to me:

1. [How can I change the color of the header in a xyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908188/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-header-in-a-xyplot)
2. [change background and text of strips associated to multiple panels in R / lattice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536239/change-background-and-text-of-strips-associated-to-multiple-panels-in-r-lattic/8537752#8537752)
3. [assigning colours to plots in lattice according to Set or factor, not groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283828/assigning-colours-to-plots-in-lattice-according-to-set-or-factor-not-groups)
4. [Change default colour lines xyplot with referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329837/change-default-colour-lines-xyplot-with-referencing)

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

For convenience, the dput(df):

```
dput(df)
    structure(list(clust = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), 
    .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = c("F", "M", "M", "F", "F"), 
    conf = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L), 
    chall = c(6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L)), 
    row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot options to the symbols are passed via the `par.settings` argument, which takes a list as an argument and can be used to set colors, point size, etc.

```
xyplot(chall ~ conf, 
   data = df,
   group = gender, 
   auto.key = list(space = 'right'),
   jitter.x = T, jitter.y = T,
   par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(
    col = c("pink", "blue"), pch=16)))
```